# Styling Error checking elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, styling

I have this code and it displays my errors, I am trying to style the three validations below the Please Correct the errors below..is this possible?

```
if (name == '' || name.length <= 2) {
        valid = '<p>Your name' + required +'</p>';  
    }

    if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
        valid += '<p>Your email' + required +'</p>';                                                  
    }

    if (mydropdown == '') {
        valid += '<p>An item from the list' + required +'</p>';

    }



    // let the user know if there are erros with the form
    if (valid != '') {

        $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error strong')
            .html('<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' +valid).fadeIn('fast');   


    }
```

Comment: If you add classes to the `<p>` tag, then you can style them using CSS.

Comment: well I feel dumb, thank you for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the `<p>` tag and add style using CSS.

```
if (name == '' || name.length <= 2) {
    valid = '<p class="error">Your name' + required +'</p>';  
}

if (!email.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
    valid += '<p class="error">Your email' + required +'</p>';                                                  
}

if (mydropdown == '') {
    valid += '<p class="error">An item from the list' + required +'</p>';

}
```

In your CSS file:

```
p.error {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* whatever style you want */
}
```

Comment: quick question I have a php message that appears once it is submitted..its wrapped in a p tag but in my php file when I try to add a class it wont work..i dont know anything of php really, suggestion?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is it not being styled or is the class not there?

Comment: You can come to [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21852/styling-error-checking-elements) if you want help with this